# How do you choose appropriate parameters for a lowpass filter when filtering a Bouguer anomaly?

Tags: geology, geophysics, models, gravity

I am trying to filter my Bouguer anomaly data to remove the short wavelength features. I have created a lowpass filter to achieve this, but I am wondering how I can more objectively choose my cutoff wavelength(s).  This filtering is done in the Fourier domain.

The filtering technique is similar to what is described in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266079150_A_Methodology_for_Filtering_and_Inversion_of_Gravity_Data_An_Example_of_Application_to_the_Determination_of_the_Moho_Undulation_in_Morocco).

Currently, I am just very loosely basing the wavelengths off of my elastic plate thickness, and comparing (via observation and RMSE) the resulting Bouguer anomaly to my predicted model.

Comment: I am now wondering if it would make sense to instead base the filter wavelength off of the assumed crustal thickness instead of Te.

Comment: if this is about an electronic bandpass filter you might try to ask this question in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, this is in regard to applying a digital filter to remove high frequency (short wavelength) gravitational variations.  Since my issue has more to do with choosing the most appropriate wavelengths to filter out, not the implementation, I thought the Earth Science community would have more knowledge than say DSP or electronics.